# Recursive factorial calculations in Rust

Tags: beginner, mathematics, integer, rust

I am trying to calculate very large factorials. I am looking to speed it up as `10000!` takes approximately a minute and a half.

```
extern crate num;
use num::bigint::BigInt;
use num::bigint::ToBigInt;

fn tree_fact(n: u64) -> BigInt {
    if n < 2 {
        return 1.to_bigint().unwrap();
    }
    return factorial(1, n)
}


fn factorial(low: u64, high: u64) -> BigInt {
    if low +1 < high {
        let mid = (low + high) / 2;
        return factorial(low, mid) * factorial(mid + 1, high)
    }
    if low == high {
        return low.to_bigint().unwrap();
    }
    return low.to_bigint().unwrap() * high.to_bigint().unwrap();

}


fn main() {
    let fac_value = tree_fact(10000);
    println!("{}", fac_value);
}
```

I am also concerned with following best practices as I am new to programming in Rust so feel free to point out where I am bending any rules.

Comment: I don't know your context, but sometimes an approximation of a very large factorial can be enough and can be calculated much **much** faster. In this case there is the [Stirling's approximation formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html) you might want to look at :)

Comment: Thanks. However, I believe in my case I need it to be exact. :(

Comment: I'll try to write an answer today, I got something for you! :)

Comment: I figured that your algorithm is more efficient than the one I thought about. But, I find it hard to believe `10000!` factorial is so long to compute, on my computer the basic factorial method takes some milliseconds

Comment: Yeah, factorials up to about `2000!` are really quick. Then they start to slow down.

Comment: If you want, try the method I made on [this question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106963/faster-factorial-calculations). I don't know if it'll be faster though..

Comment: That is an interesting post, lots of math I really don't understand in there. However, I am still looking for ways to increase the efficiency of this algorithm.

Comment: http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm

Comment: An easier way than the link above is to make a `BinaryHeap<BigInt>` and reduce it by multiplying the smallest two elements, although this is a heuristic approach that only helps a little.